# How to get certain values from a MxN array into a column vector?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a big MxN array and I want some values in this array to be moved into a column vector. The x and y coordinates of the values that I need are stored in two separate arrays `X` and `Y` respectively.

For example, lets call the MxN array `Arr` and its size is 288x384. Let `X = [23,288,56]`, `Y = [233,45,23]`. Then I want `Arr(23,233)`, `Arr(288,45)` and `Arr(56,23)` in a column vector `Col`.

Comment: What's the criteria for "some"?

Comment: I have the x and y coordinates of those values I need.

Comment: Can you actually include a meaningful example of code, along with the required input and the desired output in your question?

Comment: Please give an example for better description.

Comment: Hope the example helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
Arr = [1 3 4
       5 2 6];
X = [1 2 2];
Y = [3 1 2];

result = Arr(sub2ind(size(Arr), X(:), Y(:)));
```